# Pull a list of certain OS from AD

Tags: powershell

First I am new to using PowerShell, so if this seems a little simple, I apologize.
I am attempting to get an inventory of 2003 servers in my environment.
So far this is what I have:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter *2003* -Property * | Format-Table Name,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemServicePack
```

I get an error with syntax.  The parsing seems to get hung up on the Filter attribute.  How can I only display the 2003 servers in my environment?

Thanks.

Comment: Here is the [MSDN page on the cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617192.aspx) the section on the `-Filter` Property should also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about the duplicate request.  Here is my final code:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {(OperatingSystem -like "*windows*server*2003*") -and (Enabled -eq "True")} -Properties * | Sort Name | Format-Table Name,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemServicePack,OperatingSystemVersion
```

Thanks for your help.